# Live Agent Chat - How Do You Append A Value From The Prechat Form To A Chat Conversation?

Tags: liveagent, chat, pre-chat

I currently have a textarea on my prechat form that looks like:

```
<textarea name='liveagent.prechat:CaseSubject' class="form-control-desc" id='subject' cols="75" rows="3" maxlength="255"  size="250" 
          onkeydown="return this.value.substr(0,240)" required="true"/>
```

The value entered into this textarea is then appended to the subject line of the case ticket created.  I would like this value to also be added to the chat conversation itself as the first message that the user typed.

Is there an element `name` I can associate with the textarea element to make this happen?